# How to put a CASE statement in the GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table with one column that is a comma separated list of possible values.  I'd like to query, grouped by each individual possible value.

As a test, I've written this query:

```
SELECT
    `Please_identify_which_of_the_following_classroom_hardware_you_c2`,
    count(`_How_would_you_rate_your_overall_skill_in_using_educational_tec1`) as count,
    `_How_would_you_rate_your_overall_skill_in_using_educational_tec1`
FROM
    `data_Copy_of_Faculty_survey_on_technology_in_the_classroom_Respo`
GROUP BY
    `_How_would_you_rate_your_overall_skill_in_using_educational_tec1`,
    CASE
        WHEN `Please_identify_which_of_the_following_classroom_hardware_you_c2` LIKE '%Elmo%' THEN 'Elmo'
    END
```

(Please excuse the column names, they're auto-generated)

I know the CASE statement isn't incredibly useful at this point, but I'm just trying to get the query to run.  I'm getting an error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'THEN 'Elmo' END' at line 10

For the life of me I can't find what's wrong with the query.  Any insight would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** I've tried with single and double quotes - same problem regardless of the quote used.

**UPDATED:** As Mark has pointed out, even if I get this query to parse, the results won't be what I'm looking for.  I'm still curious why this doesn't parse, but the query is not the solution to my initial problem.

Comment: Try using single quotes instead of double.

Comment: Are you in ANSI_QUOTES mode? If so, you must use single quotes where double would otherwise be supported for strings. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html

Comment: I've tried with single quotes, and it's the same problem.

Comment: I wonder if you have a non-printable character in there. The syntax looks fine to me. Try erasing and retyping it because it's definitely failing between `LIKE "%Elmo%"` and the following `THEN` keyword

Comment: Hmm, though [the manual says `END CASE` is supported](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) I just tried a `CASE` in `GROUP BY` and got a syntax error unless I wrote it as `CASE WHEN THEN END`, omitting the final `CASE` from `END CASE`...  Apparently the `END CASE` is used in procedural code..

Comment: The syntax does differ for a flow control function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: Are you executing this as a query buried in other code or directly in a SQL editor?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Re-typing didn't fix anything.  Changing from "END CASE" to "END" didn't either.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I'm running this directly on the command line, after logging in to MySQL

Comment: Can you edit above to show your current exact code? Changing `END CASE` to just `END` would correct one problem even if it isn't the problem you're currently experiencing. What MySQL version are you connected to?

Comment: Wow, you're right at the character length limit for a column name (64) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html. I'm not sure how MySQL fails if it's too long.

Comment: @Michael's right, you need to change `END CASE` to `END` when a `CASE` is inline. Combine that with switching double quotes to single quotes.

Comment: Updated.  I know I'm right close to the limit - that's why the column names end in "c2" and "1".  The table is auto-generated from a CSV, so the titles needed to be truncated.

Comment: So... I know I'm getting ahead of things with this, but based on what you said you're trying to do you might want to start thinking about it if you haven't...  the CASE logic you're attempting, should you get it to work, will still only assign each row to the first group that row matches.  So if you had a case for `LIKE '%ELMO%'` and a case for `LIKE "%BERT%"` and a row with value 'BERT,ELMO' that row will get included in the ELMO count but not the BERT count...

Comment: Thanks @MarkAdelsberger I wasn't sure if that was going to be the case - but I see now that you've said it, that's totally what will happen.  So I guess I'm barking up a wrong tree.  Any tips as to how to get around this?

Comment: All I can think of is that you have a special character embedded in there somewhere. Sorry, but the syntax looks good. All I can suggest is to open a new query window and type the whole query manually. And do not use the back-ticks either.

Comment: mysql isn't one of the DBMS's I'm super familiar with...  off hand, can you do each count in a separate column (`SELECT ... , count(CASE WHEN colname LIKE '%ELMO%' THEN 1 END) ELMO, count(CASE WHEN colname LIKE '%BERT%' THEN 1 END) BERT, ...`); so you'd group only by `How_would_you_rate_blahblahblah` and get all counts for a rating on a single row, which I suppose you might then have to unpivot

Comment: Do you use version 5.7 of MySql or some earlier version ? Could you run `SELECT @@ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY;` and show us a result of this query ?

Comment: @krokodilko I'm using 5.5.  Running that query returns an error about an unknown system variable.

Comment: Sorry, this above syntax is not for sql_mode variable, please run `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;` and check if `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is enabled.

Comment: @krokodilko It returns 1 row, which is empty.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're seeing issues is that your `GROUP BY` attributes didn't align with the `SELECT` attributes.

As the [MySql docs put it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html):

```
"SQL92 and earlier does not permit queries for which 
the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer 
to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY 
clause nor are functionally dependent on (uniquely determined by)
GROUP BY columns"
```

In other words, since the `...c2` attribute was not "functionally dependent on" your `CASE ... END` attribute, there was a mismatch between `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`, and thus an error.

One way to mitigate the error (and possibly make the query more readable), is to do the `CASE` once and then do the aggregates on the resulting relation.

```
SELECT c2, tec1, COUNT(tec1)
FROM  
    (SELECT
       CASE 
         WHEN `Please_identify_which_of_the_following_classroom_hardware_you_c2` LIKE '%Elmo%' 
           THEN 'Elmo'
         ELSE
         `Please_identify_which_of_the_following_classroom_hardware_you_c2`
       END AS c2,
      `_How_would_you_rate_your_overall_skill_in_using_educational_tec1`) AS tec1
    FROM 
      `data_Copy_of_Faculty_survey_on_technology_in_the_classroom_Respo`) t
GROUP BY c2, tec1
```

Comment: If this is really the answer, the error message shown should be something entirely different. Coming here as an MSSQL guy, it sent me on a wild goose chase. MSSQL would have just said that something included in the group by was not included in the select statement. Syntactically that query was fine, but semantically it was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN `Please_identify_which_of_the_following_classroom_hardware_you_c2` LIKE '%Elmo%' THEN 'Elmo'
        ELSE `Please_identify_which_of_the_following_classroom_hardware_you_c2`
    END AS `Please_identify_which_of_the_following_classroom_hardware_you_c2`,
    count(`_How_would_you_rate_your_overall_skill_in_using_educational_tec1`) as count,
    `_How_would_you_rate_your_overall_skill_in_using_educational_tec1`
FROM
    `data_Copy_of_Faculty_survey_on_technology_in_the_classroom_Respo`
GROUP BY
    `_How_would_you_rate_your_overall_skill_in_using_educational_tec1`,
    CASE
        WHEN `Please_identify_which_of_the_following_classroom_hardware_you_c2` LIKE '%Elmo%' THEN 'Elmo'
    ELSE `Please_identify_which_of_the_following_classroom_hardware_you_c2`
        END
```

Comment: That runs.  The returned resultset looks pretty inconsistent though.

Comment: Sorry, I left the ELSE out of the GROUP BY clause.  The Case Statement should be identical in the Select and Group By... Is this better?  -- I apologize for my poor formatting.  This is the first time I've posted here.  I'll figure it out :).

Comment: I have sufficient reputation to edit your post - so I did.  This resultset looks a little better.  Thanks.  However, as Mark pointed out in his comment above, the philosophy behind this query won't get me what I want, so I think I'm going to have to not group by a case, and collate the data in code after the query is run.  Nonetheless - thanks for your help.